# Not overwrite string using drawString on canvas android

Tags: android

I am writing a string on imageview. Right now when the finger is touched on imageview , the previous string is overwritten. I would like to not overwrite the previous string every time the finger is touched on different place in imageview. How can I accomplish that.Thanks

```
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


 switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    Bitmap.Config config = bm.getConfig();
                    int width = bm.getWidth();
                    int height = bm.getHeight();

                    bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);

                    c = new Canvas(bm2);
                    c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

                    paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setTextSize("14");
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    paint.setTypeface(TYPEFACE.NORMAL);

                   c.drawText(words, x, y, paint);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bm2);


                    break;


 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;

            }


            return true;
```

Comment: Please be more specific: What do you want to happen on repeated touches: Do you want to keep the previous image?

Comment: I would like the same string to be written in imageview every time imageview is touched.